# Singleton pattern on persistent in-memory cache

Tags: c#, architecture, .net-3.5, singleton

Using what I judged was the best of all worlds on the [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html) amazing article, I have been using with success the following class to persist user-defined data in memory (for the very rarely modified data):

```
public class Params
{
  static readonly Params Instance = new Params();

  Params()
  {
  }

  public static Params InMemory
  {
    get
    {
      return Instance;
    }
  }

  private IEnumerable<Localization> _localizations;

  public IEnumerable<Localization> Localizations
  {
    get
    {
      return _localizations ?? (_localizations = new Repository<Localization>().Get());
    }
  }

  public int ChunkSize
  {
    get
    {
      // Loc uses the Localizations impl
      LC.Loc("params.chunksize").To<int>();
    }
  }

  public void RebuildLocalizations()
  {
    _localizations = null;
  }

  // other similar values coming from the DB and staying in-memory,
  // and their refresh methods

}
```

My usage would look something like this:

```
var allLocs = Params.InMemory.Localizations; //etc
```

Whenever I update the database, the RefreshLocalizations gets called, so only part of my in-memory store is rebuilt. I have a *single* production environment out of about 10 that *seems* to be misbehaving when the RefreshLocalizations gets called, not refreshing at all, but this is also seems to be intermittent and very odd altogether.

My current suspicions goes towards the singleton, which I think does the job great and all the unit tests prove that the singleton mechanism, the refresh mechanism and the RAM performance all work as expected.

That said, I am down to these possibilities:

1. This customer is lying when he says their environment is not using loading balance, which is a setting I am not expecting the in-memory stuff to work properly (right?)
2. There is some non-standard pool configuration in their IIS which I am testing against (maybe in a Web Garden setting?)
3. The singleton is failing somehow, but not sure how.

Any suggestions?

**.NET 3.5** so not much parallel juice available, and not ready to use the Reactive Extensions for now

Edit1: as per the suggestions, would the getter look something like:

```
public IEnumerable<Localization> Localizations
{
  get
  {
    lock(_localizations) {
      return _localizations ?? (_localizations = new Repository<Localization>().Get());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is is possible you have some thread safety issues here?  Seems like you would want to have a lock to prevent multiple instances of your repository from being created after a refresh (commonly called a "cache stampede")

Comment: Thanks for your comment Eric, I assumed the way I call the repository using the InMemory instance would prevent that from happening, does that makes sense?

Comment: From you question it sounds like the code to post would be the code that does the refresh.  What you have above looks ok to me.  Load balancing and IIS should not have any effect (but again would need to see the db refresh code), unless you are referring to multiple webservers in which case you will need to synchronise the refresh across them (which which case just use an external cache....AppFabric cache would be suitable)

Comment: @F.Aquino: Actually, no, it doesn't. It could very well be that two threads try to access the `Localization` property at nearly the same time, leading to two repositories being created. Making this property thread safe will get rid of this problem. In other words: Your singleton class is not thread safe after the instance has been created.

Comment: As Eric said, there definitely could be some threading issues as you are not locking around the _localizations member (and the ?? call).  However you said the data is rarely updated...are you sure of that?

Comment: Another possibility is that there are two or more virtual folders on the same web server running the application but both using the same database.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Agree totally with what you have said...the design is not great...however creating multiple repositories shouldn't cause the issue that he is seeing (where the data appears not to be updating).  My guess is that the Rebuild code is not getting called somehow (or there are multiple web servers)

Comment: @MikeHanrahan what would you suggest for the design without going with something in the ways of a Redis or similar?

Comment: @F.Aquino I think first you need to establish if the problem is due to multiple machines.  If it is then you need to either use a third cache (Redis/AppFabric etc.) or if as you say you want to avoid that, then you need some method to inform the other machines that they need to rebuild the data.  If you are using SQL Server I have found the Service Broker to be effective for notifying when to update in memory data, or a simple message might suffice (something like 0mq/ZeroMQ which can be installed from NuGet).

Comment: @F.Aquino I should add that you should amend your Singleton to account for the threading issues mentioned by the other posters, but I don't think thats the source of your problem.  Also, is there any reason you didn't use a simple static class?  Singletons can be useful if you are implmenting an interface, or need to inherit from a base class, but you don't seem to be doing that, so a static class might be just as effective.

Comment: @MikeHanrahan Thank you, I rarely ask anything around and I learned a ton with this one -- I went the singleton route by looking at the HttpContext (.Current) and NHibernate's SessionFactory at the time if I remember correctly, I knew it was a heavy thing floating in memory rarely updated, I will run the tests against a simple static class and would like to thank you for all the input.

Comment: @F.Aquino No problem.  Bare in mind that all the properties on your static class need to be locked/thread safe just as with the Singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, here is how you might make the `Localizations` property thread safe:

```
public class Params
{
  private object _lock = new object();

  private IEnumerable<Localization> _localizations;    
  public IEnumerable<Localization> Localizations
  {
    get
    {
      lock (_lock) {
         if ( _localizations == null ) {
            _localizations = new Repository<Localization>().Get();
         }

         return _localizations;
      }
    }
  }

  public void RebuildLocalizations()
  {
     lock(_lock) {
        _localizations = null;
     }
  }

  // other similar values coming from the DB and staying in-memory,
  // and their refresh methods

}
```

Comment: Eric, thanks, the _lock approach has any advantages from locking the instance variable itself?

Comment: @F.Aquino - Yes, since you are assigning to the instance variable, you don't also want to lock on it as your lock will be inadvertently released when you reassign the object.  See the first answer on this question for a good explaination: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287356/c-sharp-threading-lock-object

Comment: Thank you Erik, I went with your suggesting and will start the QA today, I would like to thank everyone else that contributed to the thread, amazing and quick feedback, sadly these major questions that I see so many people getting wrong aren't asked as much.

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in creating a thread safe singleton, if your properties are not going to be thread safe.

You should either lock around assignment of the `_localization` field, or instantiate in your singleton's constructor (**preferred**). Any suggestion which applies to singleton instantiation applies to this lazy-instantiated property.

The same thing further applies to all properties (and their properties) of `Localization`. If this is a Singleton, it means that any thread can access it any time, and simply locking the getter will again do nothing.

For example, consider this case:

```
    Thread 1                              Thread 2

    // both threads access the singleton, but you are "safe" because you locked
1.  var loc1 = Params.Localizations;      var loc2 = Params.Localizations;

    // do stuff                           // thread 2 calls the same property...
2.  var value = loc1.ChunkSize;           var chunk = LC.Loc("params.chunksize");

    // invalidate                         // ...there is a slight pause here...
3.  loc1.RebuildLocalizations();

                                          // ...and gets the wrong value
4.                                        var value = chunk.To();
```

If you are only reading these values, then it might not matter, but you can see how you can easily get in trouble with this approach.

Remember that with threading, you never know if a different thread will execute something between two instructions. **Only simple 32-bit assignments are atomic**, nothing else.

This means that, in this line here:

```
return LC.Loc("params.chunksize").To<int>();
```

is, as far as threading is concerned, equivalent to:

```
var loc = LC.Loc("params.chunksize");
Thread.Sleep(1); // anything can happen here :-(
return loc.To<int>();
```

Any thread can jump in between `Loc` and `To`.

Comment: Your second approach is something I've never seen, very interesting, so the constructor approach won't require the lock wrapper? Would that also eliminate the instance variable _localizations and I would simply set the Localizations property using an auto-property?

Comment: @F.Aquino: yes and no; it would still imply a `private readonly` backing field `_localizations`, to prevent anyone from accidentally changing it, since there is no locking. Leaving the `set` accessor would fix nothing. But in that case, you wouldn't have the possibility to "rebuild" it by invalidating it. If this is what you are after, go for regular locking, that's your only option.

Comment: @F.Aquino: I've updated my answer with additional info. Btw, why is this called "Localizations"? What does it have with localization actually?

Comment: It is a quick translation from the actual portuguese domain-specific name for a multi-language site, probably poorly chosen.